# Enum not binding to property in ASP.NET JSON request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, enums, json.net, model-binding

I am not sure why my enum of the type ScheduleType doesnt bind to the property Type in the json below.  The other properties bind find, and I havent had an issue with an enum binding in other places, thoughts?  It always defaults the the first one.

**JSON**

```
{"Id":0,"BulkInsertId":null,"DivisionId":10406,"DivisionName":"17","DivisionOrder":1,"Type":1,"Name":"A1 vs. A2" }
```

**Class**

```
public class ScheduleMatchupModel : IScheduleMatchupModel
    {
        public ScheduleType Type { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DivisionId { get; set; }
        public int? DivisionOrder { get; set; }
        public string DivisionName { get; set; }
```

**IScheduleMatchupModel.cs**

```
public interface IScheduleMatchupModel
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    ScheduleType Type { get; set; }
```

**ScheduleType Enum**

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public enum ScheduleType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "0")]
    All = 0,
    [EnumMember(Value = "1"), Display(Name = "Pool Play")]
    Pool,
    [EnumMember(Value = "2"), Display(Name = "Bracket Play")]
    Bracket
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By means of the EnumMember attribute you set certain values to your enums:

```
[EnumMember(Value = "0")]
All = 0,
[EnumMember(Value = "1"), Display(Name = "Pool Play")]
Pool,
[EnumMember(Value = "2"), Display(Name = "Bracket Play")]
Bracket
```

The only problem is that the Value property of [EnumMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute is a string:

```
public string Value { get; set; }
```

And you assign integers to your enums in your JSON:

```
{...,"Type":1,... }
```

You should therefore try to change it to string in your JSON:

```
{..."Type":"1",... }
```

Comment: Removing EnumMember has same effect

Comment: I made the property a string in Javascript and it works.  Kind of weird there isnt a way around this.